# Want to extract the a text from a tag

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column in a table where the data is stored in below format

```
  <Server start>
  <message tagid=" ">false</message>
  <message tagid="34">no data found</message>
  <message tagid=" ">false</message>
  <Server stop>
```

Where I need to extract "no data found". Tried using regexp replace function but couldnot make it in a proper way.

Note: message tag id (number) can be of any length.

Comment: Can you show us what the table and data actually looks like?

Comment: Really? Do you need to extract "no data found", no matter where it is? Then just do `select 'no data found' from ...` OK, so that is **not** the requirement, is it? What do you need to extract - the message where the tagid is not a single space? What if there is more than one such message?

Comment: @mathguy the message is populated dynamically so I  couldn't extract directly using select. Next, there may be multiple message tagids but only one tag id will have a number and a message assigned to it respectively. So I need to find that tagid which contains a number.

Comment: @bobC please consider a table with 3 columns . 1st column stores id, 2nd column stores frequency,3rd column stores message(the content mentioned above). I need to run a query for each id to filter the message tag id's value. Considering the message varies according to each id.

Comment: Clear as mud...

Answer (score 1):

**Query**:

```
SELECT x.tagid,
       x.message
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTable(
         '/Server/message'
         PASSING XMLType(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE( t.your_column, '<Server start>', '<Server>' ),
                     '<Server stop>',
                     '</Server>'
                   )
                 )
           COLUMNS tagid   VARCHAR2(100) PATH './@tagid',
                   message VARCHAR2(400) PATH './text()'
       ) x;
```

**Output**

```
TAGID MESSAGE
----- -------
      false
34    no data found
      false
```

If you just want the values where the message is `no data found` then add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query:

```
WHERE x.message = 'no data found';
```

Comment: Or rather, from the OP's comment below the question, where tagid is not null. Or maybe != ' '.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your query based on the following code. First converting your text to XML, then extract neccesary data by using XMLType.extract() function

```
with test_query as (select XMLType(replace(replace(s,'<Server stop>','</Server>'),'<Server start>','<Server>')) xml from
(select '<Server start>
  <message tagid=" ">false</message>
  <message tagid="34">no data found</message>
  <message tagid=" ">false</message>
  <Server stop>' as s from dual)) 
  select 
         t.xml.extract('//message[position()=2]/text()') out
   from test_query t;
```

Comment: actually position of the message tagid which contains error code is not fixed. For ex it may appear at 2nd position for id 1, it may appear at 5th position for id 2 and 1st position for id 3. We basically need a query which can extract error text irrespective of message tagid position. Do you think regex_replace can solve this?

Comment: if you don't know exact postion replace in my query t.xml.extract('//message[position()=2]/text()') out by t.xml.extract('//message[@tagid!=" "]/text()') out